# TextBlock filling vertical space

Tags: wpf, xaml, transform, textblock

I want to create a `TextBlock` (or some other element with text in it for display only) that is vertical (-90 transform angle), but I want that element to fill up the vertical space it is contained in, but have a defined horizontal amount (I'm using vertical and horizontal terms instead of height and width since it's swapped when I have the `TextBlock` go vertical), and have it aligned to the left side of the container.

I believe I understand how to make a `TextBlock` go vertical using `RenderTransform` or `LayoutTransform`.  However, I cannot seem to get the 'docking' to work properly, whenever I change the vertical aspect of the container the `TextBlock` increases in horizontal aspect instead of vertical.

Here is what I have:

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="AttendanceTracker.StudentView"
x:Name="UserControl" Height="172.666" Width="417.333">

<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Background="#52FFFFFF" Width="139.667">
        <TextBlock Text="My Title" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="18.667" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Margin="-58.509,68.068,49.158,70.734" Background="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="147.017" d:LayoutOverrides="Height">
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

Change the height of the UserControl and you will notice that the `TextBlock` increases in horizontal aspect instead of the desired vertical aspect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then this should point you in the right direction:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Background="Red" Text="My Title">
        <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

The key is to use `LayoutTransform`, not `RenderTransform`. This will ensure that another layout pass occurs after the transform occurs. Otherwise, the layout system is using the original bounding rectangle to layout the `TextBlock`.

Beyond that, I just got rid of all the Blend-generated cruft to see what was going on. Here's the result:

[alt text http://img187.imageshack.us/img187/1189/screenshottbv.png](http://img187.imageshack.us/img187/1189/screenshottbv.png)